# Erro com Package Control SublimeText 2

Tags: sublime-text-2, editor-de-texto

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Eu instalei o plugin Package Control no Editor SublimeText 2 para poder instalar os demais plugins via atalho no próprio sublime, porém toda vez que inicializo o Editor o mesmo aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: Imagem do ERRO]

Depois que eu aperto em OK, tudo funciona normalmente e até consigo utilizar o plugin.

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

SO: Windows 8

Comment: Você tem o git instalado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisará instalar o [Git](http://git-scm.com/), se ainda não tiver instalado.

Então acesse o menu `Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings > User`, e edite o arquivo para acrescentar o item `git_binary`. Exemplo de como fica:

```git
{
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "Package Control"
    ],
    "git_binary": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe"
}
```

Salve e reinicie o editor.

Naturalmente, se o Git estiver instalado em outro diretório, substitua `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe` pelo caminho correto.

Comment: Funcinou, muito obrigado!